# PowerShell and CSV : how can I import content of a cell? (without "@" and brackets, just the content)

Tags: powershell

I am building a PowerShell script that makes my job more optimal.

My PowerShell script connects to a MSol service. But I am trying to use a csv file which contains name, username, and password of Office365 tenant of the client.

csv file have 3 headers : Nom,username,mdpasse and when I type the name (nom) I got the good information.

In first, the script asks for the name of client, and then search in the file the good row, which contains information about the client (username and password). Now the script works, he find information about the client, but it format the result as table or with @and brackets.

So I did some modifications in the script but I know this is not the good way to do because it let some space in the result.

My script

```
   $choixDuClient = Read-Host "Veuillez ecrire en minuscules le nom du client " 
$importLogins = import-csv -Path C:\loginsOffice365.csv -Delimiter ";" 
$nomUtilisateur = $importLogins | Where-Object Nom -eq $choixDuClient | Select-Object username | % { ($_ | Out-String).Trim() -replace '@\{|\}' }  | % { ($_ | Out-String).Trim() -replace 'username' } | % { ($_ | Out-String).Trim() -replace '--------' } 
$motdepasseUtilisateur = $importLogins | Where-Object Nom -eq $choixDuClient | Select-Object mdpasse | % { ($_ | Out-String).Trim() -replace '@\{|\}' } | % { ($_ | Out-String).Trim() -replace 'mdpasse' } | % { ($_ | Out-String).Trim() -replace '--------' }

$tenant = 'tenant'
$userName = $nomUtilisateur
$password = $motdepasseUtilisateur
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$SecureString = $pass
$MySecureCreds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$SecureString

function ConnexionOffice365{
                                $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $MySecureCreds -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
                                if ($Session -ne $null)
                                { 
                                     Write-Host 'Connexion au tenant : ' -NoNewline; Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow $tenant -NoNewline; Write-Host "`r`n"
                                     Write-Host 'Etat de la connexion : ' -NoNewline; Write-Host -ForegroundColor green 'Ok'

                                     $msonline = Connect-MsolService -Credential $MySecureCreds
                                     if ($msonline -ne 'Authentication Error: Unexpected authentication failure')
                                     {
                                        Write-Host 'Services Microsoft Online :' -NoNewline; Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green " Activés`r`n"
                                     }
 
                                }
                                else
                                { 
                                    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Echec de la connexion"
                                }

                               
}
function licencesSurTenant {
                                Get-MsolAccountSku
                           }

function Show-Menu {
                        $procruser = Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow '1.' -NoNewline ; Write-Host 'Créer un utilisateur'
                        $propchmdp = Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow '2.' -NoNewline; Write-Host 'Changer Mot de Passe'
                        $propchlic = Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow '3.' -NoNewline; Write-Host 'Changer de Licence'
                        $deconnexion = Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow '4.' -NoNewline; Write-Host "Deconnexion `r`n"
                        $choice = Read-Host
                        Switch ($choice)
                        {
                            "1"
                            {
                                $nom = Read-Host "Veuillez entrez le nom "
                                $prenom = Read-Host "Veuillez entrez le prenom "
                                $affichage = Read-Host "Veuillez entrez le nom d'affichage "
                                $mail = Read-Host "Veuillez entre le mail à créer "
                                $motdepasse = Read-Host "Veuillez entrer le mot de passe "
                                Get-MsolAccountSku | Format-Table
                                $licence = Read-Host "Veuillez choisir la licence à assigner "
                                New-MsolUser -DisplayName $affichage -FirstName $prenom -LastName $nom -UserPrincipalName $mail -UsageLocation "FR" -LicenseAssignment $licence -Password $motdepasse
                                Show-Menu
                            }

                            "2"
                            {
                               $randomPassword = Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow 'a.' -NoNewline; Write-Host 'Mot de passe aléatoire'
                               $chosenPassword = Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow 'b.' -NoNewline; Write-Host 'Choisir le mot de passe'
           
                                   $choixmdp = Read-Host
                                   if ($choixmdp -eq 'a')
                                       {
                                       Get-MsolUser| Format-Table 
                                       $passwordMailChangeRandom = Read-Host "Merci d'entrer le mail "
                                       Set-MsolUserPassword -UserPrincipalName $passwordMailChangeRandom -ForceChangePassword
                                       }
                                   else
                                       {
                                       Get-MsolUser | Format-Table 
                                       $passwordMailChange = Read-Host "Merci d'entrer le mail "
                                       $newPassword = Read-Host "Entrer le nouveau mot de passe " 
                                       Set-MsolUserPassword -UserPrincipalName $passwordMailChange -NewPassword $newPassword
                                       }
                                       Show-Menu
                            }

                            "3"
                            {
                            $accLicense = Read-Host "Entrez le nom d'utilisateur du compte qui doit subir un chagement de licence "
                            Write-Host "Voici les licences sur le tenant: " ;
                            licencesSurTenant
                            Write-Host "Voici les licences dont dispose l'utilisateur " $accLicense ;
                            (Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $accLicense).licenses.accountskuid
                            $ajoutLicence = Read-Host "Selectionnez la licence à ajouter "
                            $retraitLicence = Read-Host "Selectionner la licence à retirer "
                            Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $accLicense -AddLicenses {$tenant}:{$ajoutLicence} -RemoveLicenses {$tenant}:{$retraitLicence}
                            Show-Menu
                            }

                            "4"
                            {
                                Remove-PSSession $Session
                            }
                        }

                                            }

ConnexionOffice365 
licencesSurTenant                         
Show-Menu
```

So when my script is trying to retrieve the good ID and password, it works well the problem is (I think) the format.

Comment: usually the `@{}` means the object is a complex object. i can't quite make out the exact cause in your code, but you may want to try addressing the property. you MAY be getting a collection instead of one item.that will require some way to deal with it - taking only the first/last, converting the collection to a single string, OR iterating thru the collection to create one object per item.

Comment: please SIMPLIFY your code to include only the part that deals with your problem. i THINK your problem is in the 1st four lines ... so the remainder could be removed as a useless distraction.

Comment: It may be off topic but do you really store passwords in a CSV file?

Comment: I think it would help if you could show us te first 3 or 4 lines of the `C:\loginsOffice365.csv` file. Sanitized of course, so we don't have real names and passwords. The code seems to imply that this is not a CSV file at all, but a table format output in a text file..

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution on other forum :

$nomUtilisateur = $($importLogins | Where-Object Nom -eq $choixDuClient).username

Best regards

Yoann